# Edit individual radio buttons in zend form view script

Tags: radio-button, zend-form

I have a zend form which is using a view script. I want to get access to the individual radio button items but I'm not sure how to do so. Right now, I just print them all out using:

```
echo $this->element->getElement('myRadio');
```

That prints them all out vertically. I need a little more control. I need to be able to print the first 5 options in one column then the next 5 in a second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out too. Just use

```
$this->element->getElment('myRadio')->getMultiOptions();
```

and it will return an array of the key/value options.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue. There is no nice way to do this that I have found (circa ZF 1.10.8)

Matthew Weier O'Phinney had some advice on this page:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2977

But I find that approach cumbersome in practice. The original poster on that ticket had a good idea, and I think they should ultimately incorporate some nice way to do this along those lines.

But since there is no better way at the moment, I just follow Matthew's suggestion for now.

For my form I was working on, to render just one single radio button out of the group, I had to do this:

**In my form class**:

```
$radio = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('MYRADIO');
$radio->addMultiOption('OPTION1', 'Option One')
      ->addMultiOption('OPTION2', 'Option Two');

$this->addElement($radio);
```

**In my view script, just rendering OPTION1**:

```
echo $this->formRadio(
    $this->form->MYRADIO->getFullyQualifiedName(),
    $this->form->MYRADIO->getValue(),
    null,
    array('OPTION1' => $this->form->MYRADIO->getMultiOption('OPTION1'))
);
```

That will render a `<input type="radio" />` element, and an associated `<label>`. No other decorators will be rendered, which is a pain.

For your case, you will probably want to render your radio elements and other elements using the `ViewScript` view helper - so you can line all of the elements up amongst your own custom table markup as you described.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using the ViewScript option. I don't mind the radio not getting all the other decorators. That's the reason I use the ViewScript. Thanks for the tip on the formRadio view helper though.

Comment: This seems like the best option. This will create the element like it should. Just need to be able to add a class to that and this is the best option.