# zend framework: zend form decorators - remove multiply <label>

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-decorators

I creating form element by this code:

```
$input_new = $this->createElement('radio', 'Stars', array(
    'label' => 'Stars',
    'Options' => array('class'=>'star {split:2}'),
    'multiOptions'=>array(
        '1'=> '',
        '2'=> '',
        '3'=> '',
        '4'=> '',
        '5'=> '',
        '6'=> ''
  );
```

Here what i got:

```
<label for="Stars" class="optional">Stars</label>    
<label for="Stars-1"><input type="radio" name="Stars" id="Stars-1" value="1" class="star {split:2} in_line"></label><br />
<label for="Stars-2"><input type="radio" name="Stars" id="Stars-2" value="2" class="star {split:2} in_line"></label><br />
<label for="Stars-3"><input type="radio" name="Stars" id="Stars-3" value="3" class="star {split:2} in_line"></label><br />
<label for="Stars-4"><input type="radio" name="Stars" id="Stars-4" value="4" class="star {split:2} in_line"></label><br />
<label for="Stars-5"><input type="radio" name="Stars" id="Stars-5" value="5" class="star {split:2} in_line"></label><br />
<label for="Stars-6"><input type="radio" name="Stars" id="Stars-6" value="6" class="star {split:2} in_line"></label>
```

I want to remove  at each input and 
 tag too, but main label(Stars) still stay. How i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your radio buttons could go to a display group (a fieldset), so you could as well remove all labels for the buttons and just use the group label. If not, you'll probably need to write an external decorator view. I can't think of a cleaner way to get rid of the labels.

[EDIT]

Here's an example:

In the form, set the decorators like this:

```
$input_new->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'starsview.phtml'))));
```

Then create a `starsview.phtml` file. These links should prove useful in order to figure out how to create the view script's content:

- [Edit individual radio buttons in zend form view script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962081/edit-individual-radio-buttons-in-zend-form-view-script)
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html (scroll down to the section titled "Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewScript").

Hope this helps.

Comment: it doesnt help me :( at end i simply decorate all with css rules. Havent more time ;(

Comment: Well, it's a valid option as well :D